# Logcat tab in Android Studio Arctic Fox

Tags: android, logcat

I'm using version 2.0 of the app,
and I can't find the option
to activate the LogCat tab.

In my View|Tool Windows menu,
unlike other previous versions of the IDE,
I no longer have the option to activate this tab.

I appreciate any help :-)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I have it right there, where it should be:

[image: example]

You can add a keyboard shortcut in settings:
[image]

Comment: Is there any way to add a shotcut to Logcat? In the previous version , there was Alt+6 , that opened logcat.

Comment: You can make shortcuts to everything in IntelliJ. Updated the answer

Comment: Thanks for sharing! That's oddly enough not working on Linux: Neither the view menu nor the Keymap settings contain anything Logcat related in Android Studio 2020.3.1 Patch 2. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: @SePröbläm sorry, windows user here :)